# How can I check whether "now" is in between two OffsetDateTime objects with NodaTime?

Tags: c#, nodatime

I need to set `IsCurrent` field of such a view model:

```
public class SessionVm {
    public OffsetDateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public OffsetDateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public string TimezoneId { get; set; }
    public bool IsCurrent {get;}
}
```

I thought I can write such a getter for the `IsCurrent` field:

```
public bool IsCurrent
{
    get
    {
        var currentTimeWithOffset = new OffsetDateTime(LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(DateTime.UtcNow), StartTime.Offset);
        return StartTime < currentTimeWithOffset && currentTimeWithOffset < EndTime;
    }
}
```

However, it looks like `OffsetDateTime` doesn't implement `IComparable`. Then I found that `LocalDateTime` does and tried this:

```
public bool IsCurrent
{
    get
    {
        var currentLocalDateTime = SystemClock.Instance.InUtc().GetCurrentLocalDateTime();
        var currentOffsetDateTime = new OffsetDateTime(currentLocalDateTime, StartTime.Offset);
        var currentLocalDateTimeExpectedWithOffsetAdded = currentOffsetDateTime.LocalDateTime;

        var startLocalDateTime = StartTime.LocalDateTime;
        var endLocalDateTime = StartTime.LocalDateTime;
        return startLocalDateTime < currentLocalDateTimeExpectedWithOffsetAdded && currentLocalDateTimeExpectedWithOffsetAdded < endLocalDateTime;
    }
}
```

However, `currentLocalDateTimeExpectedWithOffsetAdded` doesn't really represent what I need. From the `OffsetDateTime` class documentation above the `LocalDateTime` field:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns the local date and time represented within this offset date and time.
/// </summary>
/// <value>The local date and time represented within this offset date and time.</value>
public LocalDateTime LocalDateTime => new LocalDateTime(Date, TimeOfDay);
```

Apparently, I misunderstood the sentence and thought that it would give me the datetime with an offset.
Could you help me to figure out how can I get the datetime object that would be UTC with added offset? Or maybe there is a better way to implement `IsCurrent` field?
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I'd strongly suggest removing the use of `DateTime.UtcNow` entirely. Instead, use the `IClock` interface that's part of NodaTime. Inject that as you would any other dependency, using `SystemClock.Instance` as the production implementation. For tests, you can use a `FakeClock` as provided by the `NodaTime.Testing` package.

Once you've got a clock, call `IClock.GetCurrentInstant()` to find out the current instant. If you really, really want to use `DateTime.UtcNow`, you can call `Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(DateTime.UtcNow)`. But be aware that this is a much less testable, and less NodaTime-idiomatic approach.

I'd convert your current `OffsetDateTime` values to a instants, then you can perform the comparison:

```cs
public bool IsCurrent
{
    get
    {
        var startInstant = StartTime.ToInstant();
        var endInstant = EndTime.ToInstant();
        var now = clock.GetCurrentInstant();
        return startInstant <= now && now < endInstant;
    }
}
```

(Alternatively, create an `Interval` from the two instants, and use `Interval.Contains(Instant)`.)

Answer (score 1):

`OffsetDateTime`s unambiguously represent an instant in time, so you can `ToInstant` and compare the start and end instants with the current instant. `Instant`s *are* comparable.

```
Instant now = SystemClock.Instance.GetCurrentInstant();
Instant startInstant = StartTime.ToInstant();
Instant endInstant = EndTime.ToInstant();
return startInstant < now && now < endInstant;
```